# What is the code to allow a contract to automatically sell specific quantities of tokens at different prices?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I would use the below code to sell my tokens at a specific price (manually set by me). But, how can you allow a contract to automatically sell the first 10 tokens at 0.1 ETH, the next 20 at 0.15 ETH and the rest of 30 at 0.2 ETH per token? How would you code that?

```
function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice) onlyOwner {
    sellPrice = newSellPrice;
}

function sell(uint256 amount) {
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < amount ) 
        throw; 
    balanceOf[this] += amount;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
    msg.sender.send(amount * sellPrice);
    Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That will take some careful programming...I would probably log some information in a mapping of a struct for each token and then implement the send function algorithm to account for a total of how many have been sent. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: If you could give me an example, it would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide some example?